# Finding ID of Attached file

Tags: apex, lightning, aura

I upload a file from a form (vf page) and it shows up under the notes and attachments tab. My question is why does the name not show up when I have selected ‘myfile.name’ but instead it appears the id shows up.

[image]

VF Input line:

```
<apex:inputfile value="{!myfile.body}" filename="{!myfile.Name}"/>
```

Apex code to handle input:

```
public with sharing class CustomEmailAttachmentsForCampaigns {
public CPQ_Notes_Attachments__c cpq1{get;set;}
public CustomEmailAttachmentsForCampaigns() {} 
public CustomEmailAttachmentsForCampaigns(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
}

 @AuraEnabled
public static void testingMethod()
{
       CPQ_Notes_Attachments__c cpqNotesandAttach;
       String idofSC;

       Sales_Campaign__c newRecord = new Sales_Campaign__c(Name = 'Test account', Account__c = 'Test');
       insert newRecord;
       idofSC = newRecord.id;
       System.debug('TEST SC ID' + idofSC);
       cpqNotesandAttach.Sales_Campaign__c = idofSC;

        Attachment att = new Attachment(parentId = idofSC, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);
        insert att;
        System.debug('TEST ATT ID' + att.id);
}
}
```

As you can see it is not correctly displaying the name of the file 'name=myfile.name'

My second question is when I select ‘download attachment’ the id is missing.

Here is file upload which has the id. This was NOT done by the code above:

```
https://geaviation--jaflx.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P1F000000JN1WUAW
```

As you can see there is an id at the end '00P1F000000JN1WUAW'

Here is my version. As you can see the id of the attached file is missing.

```
https://geaviation--jaflx.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=
```

How can I get the id of the attached file and append it to the URL so I can download the file that was captured by apex:inputfile. Can I use att.id or should I pursue ContentDocument?

Comment: Can you verify with a soql query, that the names are not set to the Id? That automatically happens, if you don't set a name for your record. And in your case, it looks like that happened.

Comment: Do these attachments actually have a body?  What is `myfile`?

Comment: @NickCook myfile is a getter method. It will get the file from the line of Visualforce above